# Re-Enabling Button Based on Condition (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms

What I am trying to do is simple (I cannot figure it out of course). I am making a sample shop with an inventory system in Winform App format where if on the customer side the "Place Order" button is clicked it deducts from inventory; the amount deducted depends on the quantity of the item ordered. Anyway with this code,

```
private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

button7.Enabled = true;
//Read in value
int qty = Convert.ToInt32(nudQuantity.Value);
if ((rdoSmallCup.Checked & rdoStraw.Checked) == true) {

  //Removing four from inventory for strawberry after an order is made
  InvStrawberry = InvStrawberry - (4 * qty);
  if (InvStrawberry <= 0) {
    button7.Enabled = false;
  } else {
    button7.Enabled = true;
  }

  label17.Text = Convert.ToString(InvStrawberry);
```

I am seeing that while it does compile with no errors once the inventory for strawberry has fallen past zero (it will actually be a negative value which I do not want but is another question for another time) the Place Order button ("Button 7") will be grayed out and unusable which is the goal but once inventory is added again this button is still unusable. Can someone explain how I can have this button re-enabled (even though I said it in the 'else' condition)?

Comment: You have to query the database somewhere else to re enable the button. Just as a note, you can't click the button unless it's enabled so setting Enabled to true does nothing, it has to be true to be running that code.

Comment: That code (exactly as presented) would not compile, as it is missing opening and closing brackets... assuming this code runs in the click event handler for "button7", then the Enabled status would only change when you click the button. And as @Ron mentions, it won't run when disabled, so it would never happen.

Comment: You should enable button in place where you adding quantity to the inventory.

Answer (score 0):

Ron and Heretic's comments are right. You cannot access the code in Button7 click event handler once it has been 'disabled'. The only way to enable it again is from outside logic, say after you added additional items into the inventory, you can enable the button right after that.
Also you can can be simplify a bit:

```
private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

   //Read in value
   int qty = Convert.ToInt32(nudQuantity.Value);
   if ((rdoSmallCup.Checked & rdoStraw.Checked) == true) {

   //Removing four from inventory for strawberry after an order is made
   InvStrawberry = InvStrawberry - (4 * qty);
   if (InvStrawberry <= 0) 
     button7.Enabled = false;

   label17.Text = Convert.ToString(InvStrawberry);  
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will allow an infinite number of subtraction. Hence, you will need a control that will stop the subtraction when you go below zero.

```
private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    // I have no idea why you have enabled the button here, mate
    //Converting the quantity
    int qty = Convert.ToInt32(nudQuantity.Value);

    if((roSmallCup.Checked & rdoStraw.Checked) == true) {
        //triggers when the Inventory of strawberry is more than zero
        if( (InvStrawberry - (4 * qty)) > 0 ){
            InvStrawberry = InvStrawberry - (4 * qty);
        } else
        {
            button7.ENabled = false;
            MessageBox.Show("We are out of inventory,Sorry!");
        }
        label17.Text = Convert.ToString(InvStrawberry);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the button to possibly update every time that you change the value of `InvStrawberry` then the best option is to make a property for `InvStrawberry` and update the status of the button there. That cuts down the logic that you need to use right throughout your code.

Try this:

```
public class StrawberryForm : Form
{
    private int _invStrawberry = 0;
    private int InvStrawberry
    {
        get
        {
            return _invStrawberry;
        }
        set
        {
            _invStrawberry = value;
            button7.Enabled = _invStrawberry > 0;
        }
    }

    private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int qty = Convert.ToInt32(nudQuantity.Value);
        if ((rdoSmallCup.Checked & rdoStraw.Checked) == true)
        {
            this.InvStrawberry -= 4 * qty;
            label17.Text = Convert.ToString(this.InvStrawberry);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to move this:

```
 if (InvStrawberry <= 0) {
    button7.Enabled = false;
  } else {
    button7.Enabled = true;
  }
```

to an Updae method or loop that will check it regularly, right now its in your click, and therefore will never get called to enable it again once it is disabled, since at that point you cant click on it.

also, say you have two variables, `numberStrawberries` representing youre remaining inventory, and `lot` representing the four strawberries you put in a purchase...

```
if(numberStrawberries >= lot){
//we have strawberries, and more at least 4 or more
numberStrawberries-=lot;
}else if(numberStrawberries!=0 && numberStrawberries < lot){ 
//we have strawberries but only (remaining)

//how many were short(how many we have is still in numberStrawberries)
 int short = lot- numberStrawberries;

numberStrawberries=0;

}else{
//all out of strawberries
}
```